# C Format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *' but argument 2 has type 'unsigned int' [-Wformat=]

Tags: c

I have some problem about this code , I want to compile this but it's not compile because something wrong. I told about wrong code down there...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000                                 
typedef struct{
    int film_id;
    char title[255];
    char description[1023];
    unsigned int release_year;
    char rental_duration;
    float rental_rate;
    unsigned char length;
    float replacement_cost;
    char rating[10];
    char last_update[30];
} RECORD_t, *RECORD;                                   

int main(){
    int i,R1;
    char R[1];
    RECORD rec = (RECORD)malloc(sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX);  
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "rb");               
    if (file == NULL) {                                 
        printf("Cannot open the file.\n");          
        exit(0);                                    
    }                                                   
    fread(rec, sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX, 1, file);          
    fclose(file);                                       

printf("İd Numarası Giriniz : \n"); 
        scanf("%d",&R1);
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++){
            if (R1 == rec[i].film_id) {

            printf("TITLE: %s\n", rec[i].title); printf("Enter New TITLE : "); scanf("%s",rec[i].title);
            printf("DESCRIPTION: %s\n", rec[i].description); printf("Enter New Description : "); scanf("%s",rec[i].description);

// My problem is this line :-------------------
            printf("RELEASE YEAR: %d\n", rec[i].release_year); printf("Enter New RELEASE YEAR : "); scanf("%d",rec[i].release_year);
            printf("RENTAL DURATION: %d\n", rec[i].rental_duration); printf("Enter New RENTAL DURATION : "); scanf("%d",rec[i].rental_duration);
            printf("RENTAL RATE: %f\n", rec[i].rental_rate); printf("Enter New RENTAL RATE : "); scanf("%f",rec[i].rental_rate);
            printf("REPLACEMENT COST: %f\n", rec[i].replacement_cost); printf("Enter New REPLACEMENT COST : "); scanf("%f",rec[i].replacement_cost);
            printf("RATING: %s\n", rec[i].rating); printf("Enter New RATING : "); scanf("%s",rec[i].rating);
            printf("LAST UPDATE: %s\n", rec[i].last_update); printf("Enter New LAST UPDATE : "); scanf("%s",rec[i].last_update);

            }
        }

    }   


    file = fopen("data.txt", "wb");                  
    fwrite(rec, sizeof(RECORD_t)*MAX, 1, file);      
    fclose(file);                                    
    free(rec);                                       
    return 1;                                        
}
```

only int and float variables are not working while I was compile

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("RELEASE YEAR: %d\n", rec[i].release_year); printf("Enter New RELEASE YEAR : "); scanf("%d",rec[i].release_year);
    ^
```

Please help me ://

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s",rec[i].title);` does not prevent reading too much into `title`.  Better to use `scanf("%254s",rec[i].title);` 2) `scanf("%s",rec[i].title);` will not work to read in a tile with spaces 3) recommend `memset(rec[i].title, 0, sizeof rec[i].title);` before reading the title into it to scrub the field of random data - useful when debugging to not have garbage in the record.

Comment: Change `%d` in you format string to `%u`, to match an unsigned number.

Answer (score 7):

The `%d` and `%f` format specifiers to `scanf` expect the address of an `int` and `float` respectively.  Also `release_year` is an `unsigned int`, so the `%u` specifier should be used, and for `rental_duration`, which is a `char`, `%hhd` should be used.

So these:

```
scanf("%d",rec[i].release_year);
scanf("%d",rec[i].rental_duration);
scanf("%f",rec[i].rental_rate);
scanf("%f",rec[i].replacement_cost);
```

Should be changed to:

```
scanf("%u",&rec[i].release_year);
scanf("%hhd",&rec[i].rental_duration);
scanf("%f",&rec[i].rental_rate);
scanf("%f",&rec[i].replacement_cost);
```

You're not seeing an issue with `%s` because arrays -- when passed to a function -- decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

EDIT:

Using the proper size specifier for `scanf` is of particular importance.  If you were to use `%d` instead of `%hhd` for a `char`, `scanf` will attempt to write to a 4 byte location (assuming `int` is 32-bit) instead of to one byte, which will lead to undefined behavior.

From the man page:

> ```
>    h      Indicates that the conversion will be one of diouxX or n and the
>           next  pointer  is a pointer to a short int or unsigned short int
>           (rather than int).
>
>    hh     As for h, but the next pointer is a pointer to a signed char  or
>           unsigned char.
>
>    l      Indicates either that the conversion will be one of diouxX or  n
>           and the next pointer is a pointer to a long int or unsigned long
>           int (rather than int), or that the conversion will be one of efg
>           and the next pointer is a pointer to double (rather than float).
>           Specifying two l characters is equivalent to L.  If used with %c
>           or  %s the corresponding parameter is considered as a pointer to
>           a wide character or wide character string respectively.
>
>    L      Indicates that the conversion will be either efg  and  the  next
>           pointer  is  a  pointer to long double or the conversion will be
>           dioux and the next pointer is a pointer to long long.
> ```

Comment: @Olaf Thanks.  Fixed, plus one more.

Comment: Hmm... what if `char` is unsigned? IMO `char` without `signed`/`unsigned` really should only be used for characters.

Comment: `%hhu` can be used for an `unsigned  char`.  I agree, though that using `char` for numeric input can be confusing for the reader given its typical usage.

Comment: Problem is, with `char` for numerical input, you do not know which specifier to use. It is unseless anyway to use a smaller type than `(unsigned) int`. OP certainly has no memory space problems.

Comment: @Olaf With `char`, you have to use `%hhd` or `%hhu`, otherwise `scanf` will attempt to write to more than one byte, leading to undefined behavior.  Similarly, you need `%hd` and `%hu` for `short` and `unsigned short` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the address of the variable when you call `scanf()`

```
scanf("%d", &rec[i].release_year);
```

Comment: Same with `rental_duration`, `rental_rate`, and `replacement_cost` on the lines immediately afterwards.

Comment: He also has to use the `unsigned` format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your problem comes from `scanf("%d",rec[i].release_year);`.

The `scanf` needs a pointer to your variable in order to be able to store de read value into it. So it must be: `scanf("%d",&(rec[i].release_year));`

Note: *don't* put several commands on the same line. Your tool pointed you to the line with the error, not to the function that raised it. If you had splitted this line into 3 (printf+printf+scanf) you would have seen faster where is the problem :)

Comment: He also has to use the `unsigned` format specifier.

Comment: If I remember well it will lead to a warning, not an error, and it will work (not always as expected, but…). But yes, you're right.

Comment: IIRC a format-sting/variadic argument fault is alway reported as warning, no matter what type combinations are given.

Comment: What I mean is that printing a int with unsigned int format (or reverse) works (sometimes with strange results depending of content/types), but giving a (unsigned) int instead of a pointer to a valid memory area will lead to a segfault. But at last a segfault is better because you have to correct it :)

Comment: It is implementation defined at best. Actually, as it is a passed by a pointer, it actually violates strict aliasing rules (there is no conversion, but reinterpretation). And, no it will is not necessarily segfault, but it is UB which exactly describes what will happen. Segfault is an (unreliable) OS feature and not mentioned by the standard for good reason.